# Image not being display in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to download an image from the open weather org i have the following code.

I am using an Android Device to test my application and gave it the appropriate internet permissions.

I am using the example JSON here

https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

I no my json decoding is working fine as I see the image name in the result set under the weather object.

```
public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
 }

public async void GetWeather ()
{        
   result = await restServices.GetWeatherRequest();
   lblweather.Text = result.main.temp.ToString();
   string url = $"https://openweathermap.org/img/w/{result.weather[0].icon}.png";
   imgWeather.Source = new UriImageSource
    {
            Uri = new Uri(url),
            CachingEnabled = true,
            CacheValidity = new TimeSpan(5, 0, 0, 0)

        };
     }
}
```

My Main Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="WeatherApp.Views.WeatherMain">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

            <Image x:Name="imgWeather"></Image>
            <Label x:Name="lblweather" ></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

This is the URL that is created by my program which you will see is a valid point.

> https://openweathermap.org/img/w/09d.png

Comment: have you verified that `url` is actually valid and can be loaded in the device/emulator browser?

Comment: @Jason yes its valid was able to view it in chrome  I will show you the url it produced

Comment: @Jason please see my edit above showing the url of the image produced which is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have fixed my issue.

As the source of my graphics was from a secure (https) server, therefore, I need to change the following settings.
Android Options => Advanced
HttpClient implementation = Set to "Managed" option value
SSL/TLS implementation = set to "Native TLS 1.2+" option value